# Syncing Outlook calendar with SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, outlook

I am able to sync my share point calendar with the my outlook. I am also able to drag and drop meetings to share point calendar from my personal calendar.

However, i am facing issues when i edit the data in my personal calendar. If the meeting has been moved then the SharePoint does not move the meeting in the share point calendar automatically. I have to manually delete the meeting in SharePoint calendar and again drag and drop form my personal calendar.

Is there a better way? Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because items(appointments) in Sharepoint Calendar and your personal calendar are different objects. After the item dragNdrop'd to sharepoint calendar a new item is created.
But you can update copied meetings with outlook vb script thato would be fired each time and appointment changes in your personal calendar.

```
Private Sub curCal_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim newCalFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim cAppt As AppointmentItem
Dim objAppointment As AppointmentItem
Dim strStart, strSubject As String

 On Error Resume Next
Set newCalFolder = GetFolderPath("display name in folder list\Calendar\Test")

strSubject = "Copied: " & Item.Subject
strStart = Item.Start

For Each objAppointment In newCalFolder.Items
 If objAppointment.Subject = strSubject And objAppointment.Start = strStart Then
         Set cAppt = objAppointment
   End If
 Next

With cAppt
    .Subject = "Copied: " & Item.Subject
    .Start = Item.Start
    .Duration = Item.Duration
    .Location = Item.Location
    .Body = Item.Body
    .Save
End With

End Sub
```

full vb script example and additional functions are available [here](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/copy-new-appointments-to-another-calendar-using-vba/)